# How many larger items in top and middle levels of heap

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap, heapsort

I'm looking in a book I have for algorithms and came across this problem which I'm having trouble understanding. Using a max heap:

LARGE is the bigger half of numbers to be sorted. I.E. LARGE = { n/2, n/2 + 1, ... n }

Initially, how many items in LARGE can be within the top (log n)/4 levels of the heap, after build heap phase of HeapSort?

Let A be the items in LARGE which are neither in the bottom level nor within the top (log n)/4 levels initially. At least how many items are in A?

As found out in a previous answer, the number of elements in LARGE that can initially be on the bottom level is 2^(h-1). My theory is that if I find the ones in the top log n / 4 levels, I can subtract the bottom from the top and find the middle ones. Not sure how to go about finding the top levels though. I can assume n is large enough to make the quarter of levels even, i.e. 8 levels / 4 = 2 levels for each quarter.

Comment: HINT: You achieve the maximum in the case where one of the two children of the root is in LARGE.

Comment: wait, would it be 2^((log n)/4) ? Couldn't both of the children be in LARGE?

Comment: Things not in LARGE can't be above things in LARGE in the heap.  So if both children were in LARGE, where would the small things go?

Comment: I mean, say you have an array 15 14 13 12 11 10, 14 and 13 are in large and children of 15 right?